# check if the user is using the same IPs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ip

***I have a data frame with payments data.
I have the e-mail and the ip of the user who is making a transaction.
I want to analyze the users who are trying to pay multiple times with the same e-mail but different IPs
the two columns that I need from the main report are this:***

```
| IP              | shopper_email       |
|-----------------|---------------------|
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      |
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      |
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      |
| 204.171.147.183 | test@gmail.com      |
| 7.53.60.110     | shopper@shopper.com |
| 184.64.255.108  | hello@cloud.com     |
```

I would like to make a new column with a value that I could use as key to extrapolate the users that changed ips with something like this

```
| IP              | shopper_email       | change_ip |
|-----------------|---------------------|-----------|
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      | yes       |
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      | yes       |
| 61.184.172.226  | test@gmail.com      | yes       |
| 204.171.147.183 | test@gmail.com      | yes       |
| 7.53.60.110     | shopper@shopper.com | no        |
| 184.64.255.108  | hello@cloud.com     | no        |
```

I was thinking about a loop but maybe there's a simpler way to do this any suggestion?

like a combination with paste and match

`dataf <- dataf %>% unite("change_ip", ip:shopper_mail)`

Answer (score 1):

If the intention to check whether each unique 'shopper_email' use more than one 'IP', use `n_distinct` to find the number of unique 'IP' grouped by 'shopper_email' and create a logical vector with `> 1`, convert the logical to 'yes', 'no'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
       group_by(shopper_email) %>%
       mutate(change_ip = c('no', 'yes')[1 + (n_distinct(IP) > 1)]) %>%
       ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask you to explain this part : [1 + (n_distinct(IP) > 1)]) ?

Comment: @Andrea `n_distinct(IP) > 1` returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE.  By adding 1, the TRUE/FALSE i.e. 1/0 is converted to 2/1 which is used as position index for the vector (`c('no', 'yes')` to replace values i.e. whereever 2 is present, 'yes' will be replaced and 1 'no'

Comment: Thank you @akrun, what aboutthat ```ungroup``` in the end, what its purpose?

Comment: @Andrea Just in case, if you want to do another transformation wihtout the group attribute.  Sometimes, group attributes create issues if we don't pay attention to it